# Facebook and Google+ login is not Working In android in signed apk

Tags: android

I want to publish my app into app store.  I made the signed apk, but in that apk google+ and fb login is not working. so please tell me the how can I do that thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that you added correct Key Hash in facebook developer page. You can do it here https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android

Comment: how to generate key hash for release build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from FB developers site

> To authenticate the exchange of information between your app and the Facebook, you need to generate a release key hash and add this to the Android settings within your Facebook App ID. Without this, your Facebook integration may not work properly when you release your app to the store.
>
> In a previous step, you should have updated your Facebook Developer Settings with the key hashes for your development environments.
>
> When publishing your app, it is typically signed with a different signature to your development environment. Therefore, you want to make sure you create a Release Key Hash and add this to the Android settings for Facebook App ID.
>
> To generate a hash of your release key, run the following command on Mac or Windows substituting your release key alias and the path to your keystore. On OS X, run:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

> On Windows, use:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

More info here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash